# Adjust the JLayer playback volume

Tags: java, audio, volume, playback

How to set the volume in this simple example?
I saw different approaches before but I don't know how to adapt them for my simple snippet.

Related Questions:

1. [Changing Volume with JLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076260/changing-volume-with-jlayer)
2. [Changing volume in Java when using JLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648107/changing-volume-in-java-when-using-jlayer/2324408)

Code listing:

```
package view.sound;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Audio extends Thread {

    String fileLocation = "src/EgyptianTavernFullofGuitarists_1.mp3";

    boolean loop = true;

    Player player;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                FileInputStream buff = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
                player = new Player(buff);
                player.play();
            } while (loop);
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public void close(){
        loop = false;
        player.close();
        this.interrupt();
    }

}
```